# Solidity contract method not working on web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a method on my contract:

```
function reservePlace(address _address, uint _place) public{
    require(places[_place] == 0, "Place is already reserved");
    userIds[_address] = lastUserId;
    places[_place] = lastUserId;
    lastUserId += 1;
  }
```

and it works perfectly on `truffle`, I can execute it and works well
but when I use `web3` and I pass:

```
      contract.methods
        .reservePlace("0x95f086ee384d54a056d87dC8A64E354cC55E2690", 1)
        .call();
```

it doesn't do anything, also it doesn't show any error. Other methods work fine when I use them with `web3` so `web3` setup is correct. How can I solve it?

Comment: did u setup correctly. you need provider to instantiate a web3 instance, then you need to contract abi to instantiate a contract instance. finally u can call methods on contract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are calling data from the blockchain instead of sending it. In order for it to work, you should call:

```
contract.methods.reservePlace("0x95f086ee384d54a056d87dC8A64E354cC55E2690", 1).send({from:'your authorized address'});
```

Comment: Yeah you are right... I thought that I have to use `send` only when function is payable, how do I know where do I have to use `send` and when `call` ?

Comment: Basically when a function is defined as view or pure in solidity you will want to call them, because you are just reading from the blockchain. When you want to write into the blockchain, when you want to make any change, you want to use the send method and pay a gas fee. Also, if you want to send some ether, you specify into the send() params.